# need more aesthetic alignment for components of a figure

Tags: tables, pgfplots, floats

I'm trying to include a plot and a tabular in a figure.  I'd
like to align them prettier.   Can someone suggest a way?
Here is an image of what the included ltx code creates.
As you can see the plot has it top edge well above the top edge of the tabular.
It would look nicer, if the top edges were aligned, or perhaps the center lines were aligned.

[image: output of latex]

The latex code includes a file named [bdd-efficiency-formula.ltxdat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Oxy9llatDPICoKg6TRqZkqyCOgahXSW/view?usp=sharing%20%20bdd-efficiency-formula.ltxdat) which I've made available via Google Drive.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\numvars{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand\ROBDD{{\lvert ROBDD_{\numvars} \rvert}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}

\begin{tabular}{|rrr|}
  \hline
$\numvars$  & $\ROBDD$ & $\rho_{\numvars}$\\
  \hline
1  & 3 & 100.000\%\\
2  & 5 & 71.429\%\\
3  & 7 & 46.667\%\\
4  & 11 & 35.484\%\\
5  & 19 & 30.159\%\\
6  & 31 & 24.409\%\\
7  & 47 & 18.431\%\\
8  & 79 & 15.460\%\\
9  & 143 & 13.978\%\\
10 & 271 & 13.239\%\\
11 & 511 & 12.479\%\\
12 & 767 &  9.364\%\\
13 & 1279 &  7.807\%\\
14 & 2303 &  7.028\%\\
15 & 4351 &  6.639\%\\
16 & 8447 &  6.445\%\\
17 & 16639 &  6.347\%\\
18 & 33023 &  6.299\%\\
19 & 65791 &  6.274\%\\
20 & 131071 &  6.250\%\\
21 & 196607 &  4.687\%\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill    \scalebox{1.0}{\input{bdd-efficiency-formula.ltxdat}}
    \caption{Residual compression rate of worst-case ROBDD calculated from theoretical data as compared to UOBDD, and shown in tabular graphical form.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will not download stuff from third party sites. Just paste the content of that file here (if possible), or use some dummy stuff like a `\rule` or `\includegraphics{example-image}`.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[b]{|rrr|}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\adjustbox{valign=c}{...}` for the second object (so around your graph). In the following example I use `\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}` as a dummy for your graph.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\numvars{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand\ROBDD{{\lvert ROBDD_{\numvars} \rvert}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}

  \begin{tabular}[c]{|rrr|}
  \hline
$\numvars$  & $\ROBDD$ & $\rho_{\numvars}$\\
  \hline
1  & 3 & 100.000\%\\
2  & 5 & 71.429\%\\
3  & 7 & 46.667\%\\
4  & 11 & 35.484\%\\
5  & 19 & 30.159\%\\
6  & 31 & 24.409\%\\
7  & 47 & 18.431\%\\
8  & 79 & 15.460\%\\
9  & 143 & 13.978\%\\
10 & 271 & 13.239\%\\
11 & 511 & 12.479\%\\
12 & 767 &  9.364\%\\
13 & 1279 &  7.807\%\\
14 & 2303 &  7.028\%\\
15 & 4351 &  6.639\%\\
16 & 8447 &  6.445\%\\
17 & 16639 &  6.347\%\\
18 & 33023 &  6.299\%\\
19 & 65791 &  6.274\%\\
20 & 131071 &  6.250\%\\
21 & 196607 &  4.687\%\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\scalebox{1.0}{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}}}
    \caption{Residual compression rate of worst-case ROBDD calculated from theoretical data as compared to UOBDD, and shown in tabular graphical form.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of both centred, you could as well top align the `tabular` and the graph using `[t]` for the tabular and `valign=t` in the adjustbox. `b` for bottom alignment would be the third option.